# Cannot use home-made NuGet package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm investigating using NuGet internally to share an assembly used across multiple solutions. Despite the documentation making it look simple, I'm just getting a faceful of problems. I have two questions at this stage:

1) When I create the package, NuGet reports it as having 'no dependencies'. In fact, the assembly's project has quite a few dependencies on other (official) NuGet packages. I assumed that NuGet would spot this. Is there something I need to do so that NuGet knows my assembly itself has NuGet dependencies?

2) When I attempt to add the package to a project in another solution, it doesn't actually add the dll to the project (i.e. in the project's References). The package manager GUI lists the package in the installed list, but doesn't show a 'Manage' button, as it does for other packages. Instead, it just shows a 'Uninstall' button. So it's as if the overall solution is now aware of my package, but I can't add it as a reference to any projects, which is obviously of no use. This happens regardless of whether I install using the GUI or the command line. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For issue 1, if you are using nuget.exe pack  and your project installed certain packages, these packages will be added as dependencies. If the packages are installed to another project that the main project is referencing, do nuget.exe pack -includereferencedprojects. For more information, please refer to http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command_Examples.

For issue 2, you have probably installed a solution-level package, which does not have Content or Lib folder inside. If you install a project-level package, you should be able to see the manage button.

Hope this helps.